# C# check if delegate/func has a valid receiver

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a situation where multiple classes are registering interest with another class to observe a certain property's value. This is being done by using delegates like so:

```
public delegate void ObservingHandler (object value);

Dictionary<ObservingHandler, ObservationInfo> _handlers = new Dictionary<ObservationHandler, ObservationInfo>();

public void register(ObservingHandler handler) {

    // Observation info is created here and is just a struct
    _handlers.Add(handler, info);
}
```

This works great and is really useful but currently when a registered object is released it has to tell the relevant class that it no longer wants to receive notifications. Otherwise I get NULL reference exceptions.

Currently this means I can't use lambda expressions because the observation handler is the key in the dictionary (and so needs to be the same instance when it comes to removing it).

What I would like to do is to check that each `ObservationHandler` has a valid and instantiated class behind it before it is called. This way responsibility is taken away from the listening class.

Is there some way in `Func` or `delegate` to check the *receiver* of the function is alive and well?

EDIT:

The full source code comes from my project called [SFCore on GitHub](https://github.com/RedHandTech/SFCore).

Comment: "Otherwise I get excetpions" - what exceptions? It's not really clear what you mean - please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The `ObservingHandler` is a reference to a method in an observing class. If the observing class is released, the `ObservingHandler` contains a reference to a method in a null class. I believe the exception is a null reference exception. So right now I have to have the observing class de-register itself prior to release but I would like to be able to tell if the `ObservingHandler` has a instantiated observer attached to it.

Comment: Rather than "believing" that the exception is a NullReferenceException, why don't you show us an example? I'd expect the ObservingHandler reference to keep the target alive automatically - there's no "release" here. Basically, until you can reproduce the problem in a concise form, it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Believe is a turn of phrase. It IS a null reference exception. The problem arises specifically with unity when a component that is listening to another is destroyed by the game engine. I'm not going to upload an entire project, however I feel I've explained the problem in detail now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I didn't ask you to upload a whole big project - but you should work to reproduce it in a short but complete example. Also, if you believe your problem is Unity-specific, you should put that in the question and the tags - this is the first mention of Unity. An no, you *haven't* explained the problem in enough detail, IMO. Put it this way: I still can't help you, and I suspect I'm not the only one. You can either decide to leave the question as it is, which will leave it of less use to future readers and with a limited audience who can help you, or work to make it better for everyone.

Comment: There isn't a specific problem to highlight. The question is: `Is there some way in Func or delegate to check the receiver of the function is alive and well?` Your answer so far is to say that there is no "release". Essentially the ideal answer is `yes` or `no` and a demonstration of how to check the receiver.

Comment: If you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, that's a problem, and you should provide a short but complete program demonstrating it. There's no concept of "alive and well" in .NET, and the target of a delegate will *not* be garbage collected, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the .NET event model and let the responsibility stay with the listener, after all if your test fails for any reason, your receiver won't be notified anymore.

What I would do, is, while notifying the listeners, catch any exceptions that may arise.

If an exception arises that is due to a class no longer existing (can't be more specific you didn't gave us the exact exception name) you would then either ignore it (thinking that it's only a one-time mistake) OR remove it from the dictionary.

Again that's what I would do, there are surely other methods to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. Is there any way that you know of to tell prior to notifying a listener if the listener is actually in existence? I'm assuming that `event` does this but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

The [Observer pattern in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bashmohandes/2007/03/10/observer-pattern-in-c-events-delegates/) is achieved with events.
Using the `event` key word would be advised based on your description.

You won't need to keep track of the callbacks to at that level of holding a Dictionary as you have in your example. All you do in your call is: fire the event.

Comment: But you still need to check when firing the event that you have observers, if you don't you're gonna have some nice `NullReferenceException`

Comment: not if you always have at least one listener: event EventHandler MyEvent = (s, e) => { };

Comment: Well I took the habit of checking for null in these cases :)
But yeah that's another way to look at it

Comment: The reason I'm not using an event is so that I can bundle `ObservationInfo` with the handler. How could I do this with events?

Comment: What do you mean by bundle it together? And when is that value used?